# Segmentation Fault in Pthread Loop

Tags: c, pthreads

Recently I have been doing a bunch of numerical analysis for work. Mostly for small amounts of data on relatively simple concepts. In anticipation for a project that is coming up, I began working on more complex systems with exponentially more calculations. My run times went from being tens of seconds to tens of minutes. I decided, in an attempt to speed up run times, to learn how to write code using pthreads.

Because of this, I have been working on a program that uses a serial method and pthreads to populate matrices. I have written this program to do each of these n times and take the average time of each run. When I run this program only utilizing a single pthread_t it works as intended. When I add an additional thread, I receive a "Segmentation fault" error.

My code follows:

fill.h

```
#ifndef FILL_H_
#define FILL_H_

#include <pthread.h>//Allows access to pthreads                                  
#include <sys/time.h>//Allows the ability to pull the system time                
#include <stdio.h>//Allows input and output                                      
#include <stdlib.h>//Allows for several fundamental calls                        

#define NUM_THREADS 2                                                            
#define MAT_DIM 50                                                             
#define RUNS 1      

pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];                                              
pthread_mutex_t mutexmat;  

typedef struct{                                                                  
   int id;                                                                      
   int column;                                                                     
   int* matrix[NUM_THREADS];                                                                  
}WORKER;  
#endif
```

fill.c

```
/*This routine will fill an array both in serial and parallel with random
 *numbers. It will also display the real time it took to accomplish each task*/

/* C includes */
#include "fill.h"
/* Fills a matrix */
void fill(int start, int stop, int** matrix)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = start; i < stop; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < MAT_DIM; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
    }
}

void* work(void* threadarg)
{
    /* Creates a pointer to a worker type variable*/
    WORKER *this_worker;
    /* Points this_worker at what thread arg is pointing to*/
    this_worker = (WORKER*) threadarg;
    /* Calculates my stopping point for this thread*/
    int stop = this_worker-> column + (MAT_DIM / NUM_THREADS);
    /* Used to drive matrix */
    int i,j;
    /* Fills portion of Matrix */
    for( i = this_worker-> column; i < stop; i++)
    {
        /* Prints the column that matrix is working on */
        printf("Worker %d working on column %d\n", this_worker->id, i);

        for( j = 0; j < MAT_DIM; j++)
        {
            this_worker-> matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
    /* Signals thread is done */
    printf("Thread %d done.\n", this_worker-> id);
    /* Terminates thread */
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
/* Seeding rand */
    srand (time(NULL)); 
/* These will be used for loops */
    int i, j, r, t; 
/* Creating my matrices */
    int* matrix_serial[MAT_DIM];
    int* matrix_thread[MAT_DIM];
/* creating timeval variables */
    struct timeval t0, t1;

/* Beginning serial solution */
    /* Creating timer for serial solution */
    gettimeofday(&t0, 0);
    /* Creating serial matrix */
    for(i = 0; i < MAT_DIM; i++)
        matrix_serial[i] = (int*)malloc( MAT_DIM * sizeof(int));

    /* Filling the matrix */    
    for(r = 0; r < RUNS; r++)
        fill(0, MAT_DIM, matrix_serial);
    /* Calculating how long it took to run */
    gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
    unsigned long long int delta_t = (t1.tv_sec * 1000000 + t1.tv_usec)
                                   - (t0.tv_sec * 1000000 + t0.tv_usec);
    double t_dbl = (double)delta_t/1000000.0;
    double dt_avg = t_dbl / (double)r;
    printf("\nSerial Run Time for %d runs: %f\t Average:%f\n",r, t_dbl, dt_avg);

/* Begin multithread solution */
    /* Creating the offset where each matrix will start */
    int offset = MAT_DIM / NUM_THREADS;
    /* Creating a variable to store a return code */
    int rc;
    /* Creates a WORKER type variable named mat_work_t */
    WORKER mat_work_t[NUM_THREADS];

    /* Allocating a chunk of memory for my matrix */
    for( i = 0; i < MAT_DIM; i++)
        matrix_thread[i] = (int*)malloc( MAT_DIM * sizeof(int));

    /* Begin main loop */
    for(r = 0; r < RUNS; r++)
    {
    /* Begin multithread population of matrix */    
        for(t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++)
        {
    /* Sets the values for mat_work_t[t] */
            mat_work_t[t].id = t;
            mat_work_t[t].column = t * offset;
            /* Points the mat_work_t[t].matrix at the matrix_thread */
            for(i = 0; i < MAT_DIM; i++)
                mat_work_t[t].matrix[i] = &matrix_thread[i][0];

    /* Creates thread placing its return value into rc */
            rc = pthread_create(&threads[t],
                                NULL,
                                work,
                                (void*) &mat_work_t[t]);
    /* Prints that a thread was successfully created */ 
            printf("Thread %d created.\n", mat_work_t[t].id);
    /* Checks to see if a return code was sent. If it was it will print it. */
            if (rc) 
                {
                printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
                return(-1);
                }
        }
    /* Makes sure all threads are done doing work before progressing */
        printf("Waiting for workers to finish.\n");
        for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
            pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

        printf("Work complete!\n");

    }

    /* Prints out the last matrix that was created by the loop */
    for(i = 0; i < MAT_DIM; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < MAT_DIM; j++)
                printf("%d ",matrix_thread[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    /* Terminates thread */
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

When I run gdb I get:

```
[New Thread 0x7ffff7fd3700 (LWP 27907)]
Thread 0 created.
Worker 0 working on column 0
Worker 0 working on column 1
Worker 0 working on column 2

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff7fd3700 (LWP 27907)]
0x0000000000400924 in work (threadarg=0x7fffffffd9c0) at fill.c:35
35              this_worker-> matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
```

My understanding of segmentation faults is fairly textbook: A segmentation fault occurs when you try to access memory that isn't "yours" to access. From this I know that the code is having an issue accessing the memory where this matrix is stored.

My questions:

1. Is my logic right on the nature of the issue?
2. Why does adding a thread cause this program to break down?
3. How do I go about troubleshooting this kind of thing in the future (any tips would be greatly appreciated)?
4. Lastly, how do I fix it (clues or a solution would be greatly appreciated)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the size of the matrix of struct WORKER is just NUM_THREADS ?

You are accessing beyond the size limitation of the array you have declared at 2 places.

one is
here in main function
NUM_THREADS (that is just 2 )is actually too low compared to MAT_DIM (50)

```
for(i = 0; i < MAT_DIM; i++)
                mat_work_t[t].matrix[i] = &matrix_thread[i][0];
```

Here in the work function

```
 for( i = this_worker-> column; i < stop; i++)
    {
        /* Prints the column that matrix is working on */
        printf("Worker %d working on column %d\n", this_worker->id, i);

        for( j = 0; j < MAT_DIM; j++)
        {
            this_worker-> matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
```

the loop goes well till you access the matrix[1][j] , when you try to access matrix[2][j]  you are getting the segmentation fault because you have declared the array size as 2 and you are trying to access the 3rd one (ie matrix[2][j])

Comment: Thanks a million! I have been beating my head against the keyboard for quite a while today trying to figure it out. You have saved me countless hours of frustration, I'm sure.